# Outlook 2013 : What is the name of the log file for Exchange connections

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, outlook, outlook-2013

I am having connection issues between Outlook 2013 and Exchange 2010 where a connection is never made and even goes so far as locking me out of the Exchange server for 30 minutes.  I enabled logging in Outlook but I cannot find the file under %temp%\outlook logging for attempting to connect to Exchange.  I can see a file that contains the POP3 connections for other accounts.  What is the name of the logging file that will contain the connection information for my Exchange email account?

Answer (score 1):

Here you will find comprehensive details about Outlook logging, what is logged and where log files are saved:

https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/What-is-the-Enable-logging-troubleshooting-option-0fdc446d-d1d4-42c7-bd73-74ffd4034af5

Some additional info are available here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2862843

Comment: I have looked at the links you provided and the only location that mentions Exchange is the EASLogFiles folder under %temp% but that folder does not exist.  I have having a hard time deciphering from the information you provided what log file to look for?